# Error getting data using PDO and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm developing a web based software that uses MySQL and PHP on the backend.

I'm trying to obtain data with a complex query and in the end I just obtain the query.

```
   function consulttimes(){
$pdo = connect();
 try{

    $consult = $pdo->prepare("SELECT credentials.realname, timestamp_greenhouse.* FROM times.credentials, times.timestamp_greenhouse WHERE timestamp_greenhouse.id = credentials.id;"); 
    $consult->execute();
    $consult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($consult); 


    //file_put_contents('times.json', $json);



}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e -> getMessage(); 
}
}
```

I have all the databases and the query works perfectly on phpmyadmin. 
Can someone help me with this?

Cheers!

Comment: so, what happens when you execute it "without" the custom function? if it works, it's a variable scope issue.

Comment: If i run the query out of the function happens the same!

Comment: I've reopened the question since the now-deleted question was incorrect. @RajdeepPaul can place his comment as an answer, if he so wishes ;) and IF it fixes the problem.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks. :-)

Comment: @RajdeepPaul You're welcome. Let's see what the OP has to say ;-) *Fingers crossed*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to obtain data with a complex query and in the end I just obtain the query.

The problem is because of this line,

```
echo json_encode($consult);
```

`$consult` is a PDOStatement object returned from the prepared statement. I believe you're trying to encode the row obtained from `->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` method.

So first fetch the row from the result set, store it in a variable and then apply `json_encode` on it, like this:

```
// your code

$consult->execute();
$result = $consult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used this type of encoding before in other files, but I just did it wrong this time. I just forgot this line of code '$result = $consult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);' . Thanks you can close the threat!